# In C++0x is there something like static_assert which gives a warning instead of an error?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I would like to do this for usages which may be inefficient but not necessarily incorrect.

Comment: @Neil: Should be an answer, not a comment?

Comment: Nor should there be in most cases: treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes are introduced in C++0x for that purpose. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B0x_attribute_deprecated for an example.

Answer (score 6):

No.

An assertion failure indicates a problem preventing the program from being completed (be that execution [run-time assertions], or compilation [static assertions]).

In truth, an implementation is allowed to do anything as long as they emit a diagnostic (including continuing execution). But, in practice, mainstream toolchains will all behave pretty much the same: they will error out. You certainly can't hack them to something user-defined.

Comment: compile-time assertion failure prevents the code from *compiling*. running is out of question.

Comment: @Nawaz: I was using a more general meaning of "to run". Poor choice of word, perhaps. Allow me to pick a different one.

Comment: @Tomalak, @Nawaz - Although, if I may indulge in a bit of a language lawyering, the Standard never requires the compilation to halt if the compiler encounters ill-formed code (including a failed `static_assert`) -- only that a diagnostic message must be emitted. After this, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants, including finishing the compilation anyway.

Comment: @Tomalak : @JohannesD is correct. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177167/why-does-my-c-compiler-allow-recursive-calls-to-main/5177289#5177289) answer. A compiler is free to do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: @Prasoon: Oh, believe me, it's not that I don't trust him.

Answer (score 0):

Not as Standard, no. You can find `#warning` in many compilers, but that's really not the same in most situations.

Comment: I thought `pragma warning` was to disable warnings?

Comment: And anyway, I've yet to come across a compiler that warns about "inefficiency".

Comment: The problem is that `#warning` is selected by preprocessor conditions, which have extremely little ability to check other program content....