# Why main() in C++ cannot be inlined?

Tags: c++, inline, program-entry-point

I was reading the C++ FAQs and I noticed one sentence.

> main() cannot be inline.

Why is this?

Comment: More interesting question for me: why somebody want to try to inline it?

Comment: To inline your main in os kernel code? :)

Comment: This is silly, right?  Inlining is where the contents of a method are placed into the calling code directly, rather than being a separate method.  That means you'd need to recompile your OS to have your `main` function compiled into it.  So the answer is, because you can't recompile your OS?

Comment: @Kieren: That's why you don't ever want to physically inline the function. It's not strictly the same as why the function _shall not_ be marked `inline` (which, remember, is just a hint!).

Comment: Putting this in a C++ FAQ seems kinda silly to me because why would you want to do that. That's like when you see a warning label for a situation that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It could be in the FAQ just to make people think about what inlining actually is to avoid people trying to optimize code by inlining main and such. Personally I would see it as better to be sure to point out that it's just hints to the compiler.

Comment: I disagree with the close voters, but why does this question have ~40 upvotes?

Comment: good question, it shouldn't be closed

Comment: it is food for thought that people here think debate is not constructive. it is true that SO actively discourages debate. and it seems to me that that attracts people who do not understand the value of debate. this question is a very clear example that lack of proper facilities for debate fosters misconceptions. i.e., a technically incorrect answer selected as solution, with 80+ votes.

Comment: Related: [Restrictions on main() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144030/restrictions-on-the-main-function)

Answer (score 105):

In C++ it is not legal to call the main function in your code, so there'd be no way it could ever be inlined.

Comment: This *is* the reason, think about it.

Comment: @iammilind: `*static_cast<int*>(0) = 10` compiles too, and that does not mean that it is correct... as is the case with any ODR violation, and so many other things... the fact that it compiles does not mean that it is a legal program.

Comment: @iammilind: The statement "it compiles" requires context.  Because it's certainly not required to by the standard to compile, and it in fact does not compile in all cases.

Comment: *sigh* for anyone wondering, op asked in a comment "for a reason" then I commented answering him, but he deleted his. Not cool, op.

Comment: @iammilind: Just for the record that code does not compile on g++ with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @iammilind : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177167/why-does-my-c-compiler-allow-recursive-calls-to-main/5177289#5177289

Comment: -1 "There'd be no way it could ever be inlined" is incorrect. Plus, it's only the smallest part of the reason, a quite irrelevant part. :-)

Comment: @Alf: How is it incorrect? If I'm not allowed to call a function, then where could it be inlined?

Comment: @sepp2k: see my answer. but in short, machine code inlining is irrelevant to the question, but technically it can be inlined in the call from the runtime library, in 2 different ways. it's not done, however, since there's no advantage. :-)

Comment: @sepp2k: The function code being physically inlined is not the same as the function being marked `inline`.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach, actually it can't be inlined in the runtime library because the runtime library is compiled separately from your application and does not #include your header with the inline definition.

Comment: @psusi: you're wrong and it has already been discussed. please read before asserting.

Comment: @psusi: The linker can do inlining in certain situations.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, huh?  The linker doesn't generate asm.  That's why you have to put the definition of an inline in the header; so the compiler can see the definition and generate the asm inline.

Comment: @psusi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987020/can-the-linker-inline-functions

Comment: @iammilind: If you call `main()` from `main()`, then this call definitely cannot be inlined... (at least not recursively)

Comment: As to why main() cannot be called, you can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144030/restrictions-on-the-main-function)

Answer (score 66):

Because the standard says so:

> `[2003: 3.6.1/3]`: 
>   The function main shall not be used (3.2) within a program. The
>   linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined. **A program that
>   declares main to be inline or static is ill-formed.** The name main is
>   not otherwise reserved. [Example: member functions, classes, and
>   enumerations can be called main, as can entities in other namespaces.
>   ]

And why does it say so? Because it's trying to leave as much about the implementation of `main` to the individual .. well, *implementation* .. as is possible, and doesn't want to limit implementations by requiring that `inline` be valid here when it arguably has no practical benefit.

---

My friend on the committee confirmed this:

> There's no reason why an `inline` `main()` wouldn't work, per se. [..] I could have a C++ interpreter that can invoke inlined `main()`. [..] [But] `inline`/`static` `main()` are forbidden in order to hopefully avoid confusion. I find it hard to imagine that the rationale would be anything additional to what's already been said in [this Q&A].

---

BTW, don't confuse the `inline` hint keyword with actually inlining functions. You can mark a function `inline` and it may not be physically inlined.

So, even if it were true that `main` "cannot be inlined" (and strictly speaking it is *not* true, though inlining `main` would be rather awkward and pointless as explained in other answers), it could theoretically still support the `inline` hint keyword just fine.

It doesn't for the reason stated above, and in litb's answer: it would complicate matters for no real benefit.

Comment: +1 for quoting the standard.  However, this may not fully answer the O.P.'s question;  so far, I haven't seen any justifiable answer against, except your post.

Comment: @Thomas: The rationale I gave is pretty much the same as that found in the other answers, just with less detail as to _why_ there may be no practical benefit. :)

Comment: re "doesn't want to limit implementations by requiring that inline be valid", supporting `inline` for `main`is trivial since it can just be ignored, hence that does not limit any implementation, hence, this possible reason for the standard's prohibition does not hold water. sorry. but i don't have more to offer than in my answer, that it doesn't make sense to have `inline` (and on that we agree I think).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It would sort of imply that you can define `main` in multiple TUs if the definitions are all lexically identical (amongst other restrictions) which just makes so little sense as to be worth prohibiting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I see what you mean but... `main` being a function implies that it can be called from user code (except that's not allowed), that its address can be taken (except that's not allowed), that it's UB to flow off the end (except that that's specifically supported and well-defined), that any call must match the formal argument list (except that in practice the same runtime library call invokes it regardless of formal argument list), so on. I.e., since `main` is very special the usual implications are easily defined away. It was a good idea though. :) But didn't pan out. :(

Comment: On the contrary, you just disproved your own point by showing how many special rules exist for `main` that don't really _need_ to exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What does it mean that linkage of main is implementation-defined? Why it is implementation-defined?

Comment: @meet: Why should it not be? Unlike other functions that the user defines, `main` has a meaning that must interact with the implementation's runtime and with the host operating system (because it's the program entrypoint), so it makes no sense for a committee of people to mandate too much about it. Recall that the linkage of other functions is user-defined so, in fact, the standard _is_ constraining `main` slightly here, by saying "listen to your compiler vendor because _they_ get to choose this one not you". :)

Answer (score 27):

The C runtime library needs to find this symbol in order to "know" which function to run.

Comment: Does this mean that linkers can't find the symbols for other inlined functions?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Depends on how smart the linker is. Generally speaking, no, linkers are not aware of inline functions; they have internal linkage. More modern linkers are a bit smarter in that they'll try to do whole program optimizations, and that's a whole different ballgame. :)

Comment: I'd also say that in C runtime there is (usually) an explicit `call` to the `main()` function, and it is almost always linked dynamically. So there is just no way it could work *in a typical case*.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot directly call main() (it's forbidden in c++), so there is no point of inlining it.

Comment: "There is no point" is not sufficient reason to completely outlaw something. There's [slightly] more to it than this.

Answer (score 14):

Usually `main()` is called from systems `init()` function. Thus, it is needed that there can be **exactly one definition** for `main()`.

Now, if we can `inline` the `main()` function and include in a header file then, for every translation unit there will be different definition for `main()`. Which is not allowed. You can declare `main()` in a `namespace` and `inline` it. But not the global `main()`.

Comment: You can do this without `inline` too.

Comment: @Tomalak, then it will result in multiple definition error. Isn't it ?

Comment: Not if each definition has internal linkage. (Note, this is why `static int main()` is ill-formed, too :D)

Comment: @Tomlak, Yes. `static int main()` is equivalent to `namespace { int main() }`. Which I have covered in the answer.

Comment: One can also inline a function and only have one instance of it.  Compilers and linkers can identify multiple instances of the `main` function, so what is your point?

Comment: @Thomas, it will break ODR; if someone have multiple instances. Which instance of the `main()` to choose ?

Comment: Take the case of assigning a function pointer to an inlined function.  Which instance does the pointer point to?  There must be one instance to satisfy this condition.  Likewise, the restriction that there be only one instance of `main` would still hold.  Although an inlined version of `main` be redundant or not useful, I don't see any reason not to allow it.

Comment: @iammilind: It's not "equivalent". One is prohibited; the other is not.

Answer (score 10):

firstly you must understand how work function with inline

example:

```
 inline void f() {
     int a  = 3;
     a += 3;
     cout << a;
 }

 int main() {
      f();
      return 0;
 }
```

will look like to the compiler as:

```
 int main() {
        int a  = 3;
        a += 3;
        cout << a;
        return 0;
 }
```

looking at this example, how do you want to make main inline? This method is inline immediately.

Comment: @the_drow: I was hoping that nirmus would see this and have to think about the fix himself! Thanks though!

Comment: So what is the difference between handling an `inline`d function that has only one invocation and the `main` function which has only one invocation?

Comment: `This method is inline immediately.` Not true. `inline` is only a _hint_. It does not perform function inlining.

Answer (score 7):

Others have remarked that an invocation of `main` can not meaningfully be inlined at the machine code level. That's rubbish. It would require a bit of help from the linker (like global optimization) or else per-application recompilation of a bit of the runtime library, but it's quite doable, no technical problem here.

However, the **hinting** effect of `inline`, that calls should preferably be inlined, is irrelevant for a function that is only called once and at the top level of control, as `main` is.

The only **guaranteed effect** of `inline` is to allow an external linkage function to be defined (identically) in two or more translation units, i.e. affecting the One Definition Rule.

As a practical matter this allows the definition to be placed in a header file, and placing it in a header file is a also practically necessary to guarantee identical definitions.

That does not make sense for `main`, so there is no reason for `main` to be `inline`.

Comment: "There is no reason for `main` to be `inline`" is compelling, but not a direct explanation as why it's been made so that it _cannot_ be marked `inline`.

Comment: I have explained the same thing in my answer. However, yours is more elaborate.

Comment: Well, I think, the standard does not go out of its way to support things nobody will ever use. But I think in addition, the description of `main` is not perfect. For example, I have always thought and still do think that the "after the first statement of main" bit is fundamentally wrong. But I have never seen it discussed anywhere. Maybe, it's just my imperfect understanding of English...

Comment: @Alf: Along similar lines, the standard does not go out of its way to prohibit things unless there's a proper reason for it. :)

Comment: I disagree that it does not make sense for main to be defined in a header. There are quite a few libraries/frameworks that include an implementation of `main` that when linked, invokes your code indirectly. A priori, I don't see a significant difference between that and defining main in a header.

Comment: @TimSeguine: I agree that it can make sense to place `main` in a header, intended to be included in one translation unit only. As a matter fact I've done that ([example at github](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/cppx/blob/master/source_code/cppx/basics_and_main.hpp)). But it does not then make sense to guarantee identical definitions in multiple translation units. Nor does any other reason for `inline` then apply, as I see it.

Comment: Something like guaranteed COMDAT folding could be useful. But since the standard doesn't guarantee that, I have to concede you are correct.

Comment: The prohibition of main being inline contributed to the fact that newer embedded systems use an entry point with different name. E.g. loop() or start(). Because there compiler inherently inlines code of program into kernel's image.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard says that the `main` function cannot be inlined, per @Tomalak Geret'kal's reply.  This response discusses possibility of inlining of the `main` function, were the restriction in the Standard removed.

**Definition of Inline**
The `inline` keyword is a *suggestion* to the compiler to paste the contents of the function in-situ.  One intent is to remove the overhead present in calling and returning from a function (subroutine).

An important situation of inlining is the case where there is a pointer to the function.  In this case, there must be at least one static copy of the function.  In this case, the linker can resolve "external linkages" of the inlined function because there is one static version.

Important to note that the compiler and linker determine whether or not to paste the contents or calls a single instance of the function.

Also of note, functions that are *not tagged by the programmer* may also be inlined by the compiler.

**Inlining the main function**
Since there is only one invocation of `main` allowed, **how** it is linked is up to the compiler.  Single instances of inline functions are allowed by the Standard.  The compiler is allowed to convert an `inlined` function into a function call to a single instance.  So the compiler would **ignore** an inline suggestion for the `main` function.

The compiler and linker would have to insure that only one instance of the inlined `main` function exists.  This where the tricky part comes in, especially with external linkage.  One process for ensuring one instance is to leave information that a translation has a 'main' function whether or not it is inlined.  *Note:  When a call to an inline function is made, the compiler is allowed to remove the function from the symbol tables for external linkage, since the idea is that the function won't be called by external functions.*

**Summary**
*Technically*, there is nothing preventing the `main` function from being inlined.  The *machinery* already exists for converting inlined functions into single instances and for identifying multiple instances of a function.  When there is a pointer to an inlined function, a single instance of a function is made, so it has an address. This machinery would satisfy the Run-Time Library requirements for `main` having an address.  In the case of `inline` for the `main` function, it would be ignored but there should not be any reason to prevent this syntax (except confusing people).  After all, there are already syntax cases that are redundant, such as declaring a parameter that is passed by value (copy) as `const`.

"That's just my opinion, I could be wrong." -- Dennis Miller, comedian.

Answer (score 6):

You can only define `main` once. So putting `inline` would not serve any purpose - `inline` only has a significant purpose on functions you can define multiple times in a program (all definitions will be treated as if there were only one definition and all definitions are required to be the same).

Because `inline` functions can be defined multiple times in a program, and `inline` also serves the purpose of making calls to an `inline`-marked function as fast as possible, the Standard requires `inline` functions to be defined in every translation unit in which it is used. So compilers will usually throw away the definition of a function if it is `inline` and the function wasn't used by the code in the current translation unit. To do that for `main` would be entirely wrong, which goes to show that `inline` and the semantics `main` has is entirely incompatible.

Note that the question in your title "Why main() in C++ cannot be inlined?" and the statement you quote out of the Standard concern different things. You are asking whether the function can be inlined, which commonly is understood to insert the code of a called function completely or partially into the calling function. Just marking a function `inline` doesn't imply inlining that function at all. It's entirely the compiler's decision, and of course if you never call `main` (and you cannot do so) then there is nothing to be inlined.

Comment: The terminology in the standard is a bit awkward, but while it's true that an inline function can be multiply defined, all of the definitions must be identical, and the behavior of the code must be as if it were only defined once.  (The fact that an inline function must be defined in every translation unit that uses it is a bit more problematic.  The only translation unit which will use it is one you didn't write, delivered already compiled with your system.)

Comment: @James: re the parenthetical remark, yeah, but the Implementation is allowed to do any magic it wants. <g>

Comment: @Alf Agreed, as long as the observable behavior is maintained.  But the standard doesn't require any such magic; allowing `main` to be inline would require it.  Historically, C++ didn't like requiring magic.  (But that was before templates.)

Answer (score 3):

If you linked statically to the CRT *and* enabled some link-time compilation-inlining (like MSVC has) it might be possible to inline it.

But it doesn't really make sense. It will be called *once* and that function call-overhead is practically naught compared to everything else that is done before the first line in main executes.

...

Aaand, it is an easy way to force the symbol to appear only once in your executable. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of basic reasons.  Basically, `main` is called from
the basic initialization routine of the runtime, and only from there.
That code was (obviously) compiled without knowing that your `main` was
inlined.  Modern compiler technology is capable of inlining across
module boundaries, but it's an advanced feature, not supported by many
older compilers.  And of course, the benefits of inlining are only
present when a function is called very frequently; by definition, `main`
will be called exactly once, no more, no less.

Answer (score 2):

I see the standard says so, but the real practical answer would be as simple as stating that the runtime added to every C and C++ program has to call to some point in the executable. That function should have an external symbol (and address when running) so that the linker can find it to be called at the beginning of execution. Hence you cannot declare it as `inline`, because inlined the compiler wouldn't generate an external symbol for it.

Comment: Marking a function `inline` does not necessarily result in the function becoming inlined.

Comment: An `inline` function has extern linkage unless it's a namespace scope function that's explicitly declared `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Since its the main() function, which starts the execution, when the code gets compiled to binary, everything is in the `main()` itself. so you can say, it already inlined!

And yes, its illegal to use inline for your C++ program, that's more about a syntax!

Answer (score 1):

For most combinations of compiler/archetecture, the `main()` function in the source becomes a reasonably normal function in the final binary.  This is only because it's convenient on those archetectures, not because the standard says it must be so.

On memory constrained archetectures, many compilers, ones which produce a flat binary (like intex hex format) instead of a dynamic linker friendly container (like elf or xcoff), optimize all of the boilerplate away, since it would just be bloat.  Some architectures don't support function calls at all (only a limited subset of C++ is possible on these platforms.)

In order to support the widest variety of such architectures and build environments, the standard elects keep the semantics of `main()` as open as possible, so that the compiler can do what's right for the widest variety of platforms.  That means that many features available in the language as a whole cannot apply to the startup and shutdown of the application itself.

If you need something like an inline `main()` (or reentrancy, or any fancy feature) you can of course call the main function something else:

```
inline int myMain(int argc, char **argv) { /* whatever */ }
int main(int argc, char **argv) { return myMain(argc, argv); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline functions are having static scope by-default. It means if we declare main() as inline, it's scope will be limited to the file where it is defined. Yet, the C start-up library (provided by compiler vendor) needs 'main' to be a global symbol. There are some compilers that allow to modify entry point function (e.g. main) using linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

inline functions don't usually have an address, so there is no portable way to call main, main() needs an address on which the init code can jump into. Inlined functions are meant to be stuck into the calling function, if main is inlined, it should be inlined into the init code of the program, which is not portable either.

Comment: There's no portable way to call main in a C++ program, even if it's not `inline`.

Answer (score -2):

operating system loads binary data to memory; looks for entry point (the 'main' symbol in c/c++); makes far jump to the addres of the entry point label. Operating system does not know anything about main function in your code until the program is not loaded.

Comment: On most or probably all systems it's not the OS that is responsible for calling `main`. Instead, the OS calls the machine code level **entry point** for the program. For C and C++ that entry point is typically a function in the run time library, which in turn does various initialization chores, then calls `main`, and finally cleans up (e.g. calls installed exit handlers) and exits.