# C++ Looping and Declaring Functions

Tags: c++

Just started to learn C++ and i'm having an issue with getting a function to loop... not really sure if i'm even doing it right! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To give some context, i'm trying to build a simple degrees to farenheit converter which takes a user input for the value in degrees and outputs a value in farenheit. Also, like in python where you can use: `time.sleep()` to set a delay between messages, can you do that in C++?

Here's what i've managed to do so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//-------------------------------------------------

void DegreesToFarenheit()
{
     //Declaration
    float Degrees, Farenheit;

    //User Prompt
    cout << "Please Enter a Temperature in Degrees: " << endl;
    cin >> Degrees;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    //Program
    Farenheit = (((Degrees * 9)/5) + 32);
    cout << Degrees << " Degrees" << " is " << Farenheit << " Farenheit";
    cout << "" << endl;

}
char RepeatPrompt()
{
    char Ans;
    cout << "Would you like to enter a new value? ";
    cin >> Ans;
    cout << "" << endl;
    if(Ans = "y" or "Y")
        {DegreesToFarenheit();}
    else if(Ans = "n" or "N")
        {return 0;}
    else
        {main();}
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Degrees To Farenheit Converter V1.0" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    DegreesToFarenheit() ;
    RepeatPrompt() ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be getting warnings and errors when trying to compile that.

Comment: You can't return the function main() like that.... when you define the function `RepeatPrompt` it should return a `char`

Comment: `Ans = "n" or "N"` does this compile for your? I mean `or`, it should be `Ans == 'n' || And == 'N'`

Comment: @marcin_j, Yes, `or` is an alternative token for `||`. It doesn't mean the condition is right, but that part compiles.

Comment: @chris - The only error message I get is: " 'main' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: in C++? which version?

Comment: @chris it may compile but it does not do what OP thinks it does, the correct syntax would be `if (Ans == "n" || Ans == "N")`

Comment: @marcin_j, For sure C++03 and I'm pretty sure it was like that in C++98 as well.

Comment: @Cyber, Not quite. It's a `char`, too.

Comment: [You can't call `main()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982101/10077)

Comment: @MistUnleashed - `if(Ans = "y" or "Y")`  I know this is how you say something like this in English, but that is not the way it's done in C++.

Comment: @chris thanx, good to know, g++ compiles it but VS2005 does not like it

Comment: @MistUnleashed, You should compile with at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Don't skimp out on the warnings because your compiler will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @FredLarson - Thanks, that was an interesting article/post! Does clarify a few things.

Comment: You're not allowed to recursively call `main()` in C++ (although you can in C) - re-design your code structure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ there are 3 loops.

[while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while)

[do while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)

[for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

You want to look at your main method as the starting point of the program - and also view it as the first control level. From there you should delegate out to methods that manage the runtime of the program. If you want to reuse a body of code you'll want to use a loop and call it again. Your code example is similar to [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it), but isn't the right implementation of it nor the right time to use it. Recursion can be a powerful tool to simplify complex iterative algorithms, but doesn't fit all cases that act like a loop. It doesn't fit here.

In your case, `do while` seems fitting. Do also note that developers have style in their coding preference, and technically any loop can be used with some finesse.

**EDIT** I did a little bit of code cleanup. Much more could be done of course. Note that your teacher/online tutorial likely shows variable declarations grouped together at the start of a method. That is an old carryover from `c` days, is not necessary, and I find it messy. Keep the variables close to their usage. At the point you feel you're declaring too many variables, consider breaking your function apart.

```
void DegreesToFarenheit()
{
  cout << "Please Enter a Temperature in Degrees: ";

  float degrees;
  cin >> degrees;

  float farenheit = (((degrees * 9)/5) + 32);
  cout << degrees << " Degrees is " << farenheit << " Farenheit";
  cout << endl;
}

bool RepeatPrompt()
{
  cout << "Would you like to enter a new value? ";

  char ans;
  cin >> ans;

  cout << endl;

  return ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y';
}

int main()
{
  do
  {
    DegreesToFarenheit();
  } while(RepeatPrompt());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there any easy to understand articles on while/for/do/if loops? Also is `Void` the correct way to define a function?

Comment: @MistUnleashed: You really need a good beginner book. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10077

Comment: @MistUnleashed mouse over the loop types in my answer, those are links. Perhaps I should change the formatting of my answer.

Comment: instead of using `||` for `or` is there any way to do something like: `.lower()` (something we have in python)

Comment: @MistUnleashed consider making new stackoverflow questions rather than using comments as a medium for new questions. But yes, you can lower a char using tolower http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/. Also, if my answer resolves your question, feel free to accept it as the answer (check mark on left)