# What does it mean that linkage of main() is implementation defined?

Tags: c++, function, linkage

C++ standard section 3.6.1/3 says that

> The linkage of main is implementation-defined

What does it mean? Why it is implementation defined? Is it same in C also?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: @farukdgn: no. I amn't asking about what is implementation defined behavior. This isn't duplicate. The question is why it is implementation defined? The question you said is different from mine.

Comment: It means that the C++ standard doesn't care how linkage of `main` is implemented, it can differ depending on the compiler. The compiler isn't bound to certain criteria and thus it's implementation isn't either.

Comment: @JameyD: ok. but why?

Comment: Because an application entry point is - by definition - platform specific.

Comment: @IInspectable: How it can be platform specific? Can you give some examples?

Comment: The only purpose of an application entry point is to be called by the platform, when a program is executed. It is where the OS meets the language specification. You have to provide some leeway so that they can match up. A standardized linkage wouldn't buy you anything either, as the application entry point is only relevant to the platform running the program anyway.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982101/560648

Comment: @PravasiMeet: How can it _not_ be? Do you know what `main` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of C++ is to provide a portable abstraction over programming. Many things are specified by the standard so as to be unambiguous regardless of whether you translate your C++ to assembly, JavaScript, cheese, frying pans or supermodels.

The linkage of `main` is not one of those things, because it is a bit of an abstraction leak: it is (theoretically) the function that interacts with the pieces of the executing machine/cheese/frying pan and handles data crossing that boundary. Data in, data out.

**Substantial details about the `main` function should not be standard-mandated because the entire purpose of `main` is to interface with things that the standard cannot control.**

That being said, [there are still significant restrictions emplaced upon `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982101/560648), and in most implementations it's not even used as the entrypoint — some internal function in your compiler's C++ runtime will usually act as the the entrypoint, performing static initialisation and a few other things before invoking `main`, because, well, that's about the only sane way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Because references to the function `main` are forbidden (it helps if you quote the entire rule), linkage of `main` has absolutely no effect on user code:

> **The function main shall not be used within a program**. The linkage of `main` is implementation-defined. A program that defines `main` as deleted or that declares `main` to be `inline`, `static`, or `constexpr` is ill-formed. The name `main` is not otherwise reserved.

Linkage controls the scope across which the name is usable, the name of the `main()` function isn't usable by your code anywhere at all, so trying to label it with a linkage doesn't make sense.