# Running a C++ Qt application through a boost python module

Tags: c++, python, qt, extend, boost-python

Is it possible to run a Qt gui application as a boost module through python?  It was working as a standard C++ executable, but now I'm compiling it down to a shared library and trying to launch it from python.  Right now it just goes into the python interpreter every time I run simpleMain() from the interpreter.  As in, I get a new "Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24)" greetings every time and my program segfaults when I close the interpreter.  Also, I can't call the main function directly because I'm not sure how to convert a python list to a char**.  A string to char* seems to wrok naturally.

This is my python code to launch it:

```
import libsunshine

libsunshine.simpleMain()
```

and here's my C++ code:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libsunshine)
{
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
    def("simpleMain", simpleMain);
    def("main", main);
}

int simpleMain()
{
   char* args[] = {};
   main(0,args);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Sunshine w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your application setup in PyQt, which is as simple as

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui    
QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

at the beginning of your script. Then can call c++ code in your modules which can open/close/... windows. (I have code which works this way)

I think it is illegal to call main in c++, which might be perhaps the reason for segfault.

Comment: Is it illegal to call main? It's just another function, named main by convention. But I don't know the C++ standard by heart, so i may be wrong here.

Comment: @Torp: there is a [question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518598/is-it-legal-to-recurse-into-main-in-c) about that (and there are several others as well)

Comment: Ah well. Linkage is implementation defined. I don't think compiler writers bother to treat it in a special way though. In this case he can move main() into something called init(), call that directly from boost and call it from main otherwise. Also he could #ifdef out the main() when compiling as a module.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm usually main is called with

```
argc == 1
```

even when there are no params, `argc[0]` being the executable name.

Also `argv` is expected to be a list of pointers to strings terminated with a null pointer, while you're passing nothing. Depending on how QApplication parses the argument list (it may loop depending on argc, or it may just look for a null pointer), it can crash if passed even an argc of zero.
Try

```
char *args[1] = { NULL }; main(0, args);
```

or

```
char *args[2] = { "Dummy name", NULL }; main(1, args);
```