# Weird Stack Error Error in C in Visual Studio

Tags: c, stack, program-entry-point

This is my code towards the end of main():

```
printf("Would you like to find data on another 20 rods? \nType C and press enter to continue, or type E and press enter to exit \n");

scanf("%s",&exitOption);

if (exitOption == 'C'){
main();

}

return 0;
```

Every time I run the program I get this error:

[image]

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the definition of `exitOption`?

Comment: you should also be aware that [recursing into main()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518598/is-it-legal-to-recurse-into-main-in-c) is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exitOption must be a character

```
scanf("%c",&exitOption);
```

Even if you are trying to get a string, it must be this way

```
char string[10];
printf("Enter string\n");
scanf("%s",string);  // note the second parameter of scanf() when u get a string
```