# How come if I enter a letter input my program gets stuck in its while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Sorry if I fail to be clear enough or make any mistakes, this is my first time posting.

My code runs without errors when complied but the first while loop (in *int main*) gets stuck looping whenever a user types a letter (like `"a"`) for `cin >> select;` instead of the required `1`, `2`, or `3`.

However, when I input `"4"` or any other random string of numbers, it runs fine and goes to my error message like it should.

Why is this and what can I do to make it run normally? (run the error message in response to letters entered as if they were numbers).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void calculator();
void unavailableitem();

int main()
{
    string select;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\t[Main Menu]\n";
        cout << " 1. Calculator\n";
        cout << " 2. [unavailable]\n";
        cout << " 3. [unavailable]\n";
        cout << "\n Enter the number of your selection: ";
        cin >> select;

        if (select == "1")
        {
            cout << endl;
            calculator();
            break;
        }
        else if (select == "2")
        {
            unavailableitem();
            break;
        }
        else if (select == "3")
        {
            unavailableitem();
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "\nInvalid response.\n";
    }
}

void unavailableitem()
{
    string react;
    cout << "\n \t [ITEM UNAVAILABLE]\n";
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter 'menu' to return to main menu: ";
        cin >> react;

        if (react == "menu")
        {
            cout << endl;
            main();
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "\nInvalid response.\n";
    }
}

void calculator()
{
    int choice;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double answer;
    string choicesymbol;

    cout << "List of operations:\n";
    cout << " 1. Addition\n";
    cout << " 2. Subtraction\n";
    cout << " 3. Multiplication\n";
    cout << " 4. Division\n";
    cout << "Enter the number on the left to pick an operation: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "\nEnter number 1: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "\nEnter number 2: ";
    cin >> num2;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        choicesymbol = " + ";
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        choicesymbol = " - ";
    }

    if (choice == 3)
    {
        answer = num1 * num2;
        choicesymbol = " * ";
    }

    if (choice == 4)
    {
        answer = num1 / num2;
        choicesymbol = " / ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << num1 << choicesymbol << num2 << " = " << answer;
}
```

New code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void calculator();
void unavailableitem();


int main()
{
    int select;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\t[Main Menu]\n";
        cout << " 1. Calculator\n";
        cout << " 2. [unavailable]\n";
        cout << " 3. [unavailable]\n";
        cout << "\n Enter the number of your selection: ";
        cin >> select;

        if(!(cin >> select))
        {
        cout << "Input must be an integer.\n";
        cin.clear();
        continue;
        }
        else if (select == 1)
        {
            cout << endl;
            calculator();
            break;
        }
        else if (select == 2)
        {
            unavailableitem();
            break;
        }
        else if (select == 3)
        {
            unavailableitem();
            break;
        }
    }
}



void unavailableitem()
{
    string react;
    cout << "\n \t [ITEM UNAVAILABLE]\n";
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter 'menu' to return to main menu: ";
        cin >> react;

        if (react == "menu")
        {
            cout << endl;
            return;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "\nInvalid response.\n";
    }
}

void calculator()
{
    int choice;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double answer;
    string choicesymbol;

    cout << "List of operations:\n";
    cout << " 1. Addition\n";
    cout << " 2. Subtraction\n";
    cout << " 3. Multiplication\n";
    cout << " 4. Division\n";
    cout << "Enter the number on the left to pick an operation: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "\nEnter number 1: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "\nEnter number 2: ";
    cin >> num2;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        choicesymbol = " + ";
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        choicesymbol = " - ";
    }

    if (choice == 3)
    {
        answer = num1 * num2;
        choicesymbol = " * ";
    }

    if (choice == 4)
    {
        answer = num1 / num2;
        choicesymbol = " / ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << num1 << choicesymbol << num2 << " = " << answer;
}
```

Comment: Please read about the failbit - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read this but I don't understand. I'm new to C++.

Comment: There must be millions of similar questions about this by now. Please spend a day or three browsing Stack Overflow.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `main` in your program. Since you're calling `unavailableitem` from `main`, just type `return;` to exit the function. Also, while your program is "short" and compilable, programs that require input are usually harder to debug, especially if it requires a long string of input. Try minimizing your program so that it requires little to no input. Finally, please remove the `letter` tag.

Comment: Don't call main in your program it isn't allowed. Look at [Is it legal to recurse into main() in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4518625)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl 

Thank you both, I didn't notice that. I removed the main calls and I'm going to take a look at that post you linked Raphael.
Program still gets stuck looping but I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a newbie to programming in general, but playing with your code and looking up stuff made me find some sort of solution.
The `cin.clear` only clears the error log of the input, and I believe that it still retains the value of the letter.

What you should add right after is a `cin.ignore(#,'\n')` (# being a very, very large number) to have it avoid the line and skip right through it.

Found the solution [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input) that explains the use of both cin commands.

Comment: Oh my god. It works!
Goes straight to the error now. Thank you so much!

I don't understand exactly how this works but I will read that question you linked. I'm so happy, I was so stuck on this. Thanks again. Time to get reading and learn some things. I am quite surprised that you consider yourself a newbie but can figure out something like that since it seems so cryptic to me. 

Time to get learning.

Answer (score 3):

Ad Ed Heal mentioned, the issue here is `cin`'s failbit. When you do `cin >> choice`, and the user types "a", then the conversion to `int` fails. This sets `cin`'s failbit, making all future reads from it fail until the failbit is cleared. So the next time you reach `cin >> choice`, the user won't even get to type anything.

You can use `cin.clear()` to restore to working order.

To do this a bit more robustly, you could do something like

```
while(true)
{
    cout >> "Enter choice [1-4]: ";
    if(!(cin >> choice))
    {
        cout << "Input must be an integer.\n";
        cin.clear();
        continue;
    }
    do_stuff_with_choice();
 }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, this is starting to make more sense to me now that you cleared it up. I added your code and made a `do_stuff_with_choice();` function but I still run into the same loop error after first inputting "a" into my program.

I posted my new code above right under the old one.

Comment: You have `cin >> select;` followed by `if(!(cin >> select))`. Get rid of the first `cin >> select;`

Comment: I was referring to the loop in `calculator` actually. The one in `main` used a `string`, not `int`, and so would not get any conversion failures.