# C++ Read, from the keyboard, one character at a time until the user enters a letter ('A'..'Z' or 'a'..'z')

Tags: c++, eclipse

To answer this question:

Read, from the keyboard, one character at a time until the user enters a letter ('A'..'Z' or 'a'..'z').

Example:
   LETTER ? 4  // invalid character; so, ask for another letter
   LETTER ? .  // repeat ...
   LETTER ? /  // ...
   LETTER ? #
   LETTER ? k  // finally, the user typed a letter !!!

I wrote the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <ctype.h>

 using namespace std;
 int main(int letter){

   cout << "LETTER ? ";
   cin >> letter;
   if (!isalpha(letter))
   {main(letter);}
   else
   {};

       return(0);

       };
```

If it is a number it is working.
If it is a symbol or a letter it's saying LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? LETTER ? 
(...)

Could you please help me?

Comment: Why are you calling `main` recursively? it's a bit unsual and if I'm right it's nonstandard in C++. Use a loop instead of. EDIT: And your parameters to main function isn't right.

Comment: Yeah, this code is invalid. See: [Is it legal to recurse into main() in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518598/is-it-legal-to-recurse-into-main-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behaviour. The C++ Standard does not allow to call function main recursively.

Also this declaration of main

```
int main(int letter){
```

is not C++ Standard compliant. It could be an implementation defined declaration of main if the documentation of the compiler would describe it.

As for the repeating messages then when you entered a non-digit (variable letter has type int) stream `std::cin` got erraneous internal state and if you will not clear this state with call

```
std::cin.clear();
```

std:;cin will not allow to enter something else.

If there is no requirement that the function would be recursive then you could write simply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
   char letter;

   do
   {
      std::cout << "LETTER ? ";
      std::cin >> letter;
   } while ( std::cin && std::isalpha( letter ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current input parameter is int.
Use char or string instead.

```
int main(char letter)
{
    cout << "LETTER ? ";
    cin >> letter;
    cin.clear();            //Good to have this (see comments below)
    cin.ignore(200, '\n');  //This 2 lines will allow you to continue inputting when unexpected input is given

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only task is reading from the keyboard until a,z,A,Z is entered without printing out the letters, this should work:

```
  #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    char letter = 'b';
    while (letter != 'a' && letter != 'A' && letter != 'Z' && letter != 'z')
    cin >> letter;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace I also wonder who upvoted this answer.:) Even if do not take into account the invalid condition of if statement the program does do the same as the original program tries to do.:) In Russhia there is said usually "do not have 100 dollars but have 100 friends".:)

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @user3486543  Nevertheless it is not the same as the author of the thread want to have.

Comment: The OP clearly wants to check if it's in the range from `'a'` to `'z'`, not if it's exactly `a` or `z`. `std::isalpha` is the correct way to do this and he is already using it. Your solution is only making it worse.

Comment: @Excelcius Sorry, I'm new here and this question was sort of confusing. Do you recommend that I delete my post?

Comment: @user3486543 It's ok, the question is somewhat confusing that's true. I leave it up to you to either edit your answer or delete it. You can also leave it the way it is although some might downvote it.