# How do I get out of my current scope from void so I can get back to main? What do I need to do?

Tags: c++, class, scope, void, program-flow

My error:

```
|21|error: 'main' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

My actual program is radically different and much larger (hence the unneeded headers). I just wrote this to demonstrate my issue quickly. How do I get out of the scope of that void function and get back to main (where the menu of my program actually lies)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>

int continueint;

using namespace std;

class handles {
public:
void continueChoice()
{
    cout<<"[1] Go back to the main menu"<<endl;
    cout<<"[2] Terminate the program"<<endl;
    cin>>continueint;
    switch (continueint)
    {
    case 1:
        main();   // This is where my problem lies
    case 2:
        break;
    }
}
}handlers;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char*pszArgs[])
{
cout<<"A message here."<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
handlers.continueChoice(); //Calls the void function in the above class
}
```

Comment: The *return* keyword is powerful.  You can invoke the ten kilovolts option with throw.  But no, calling main() again is *verboten* by the language spec.  For a [good reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518598/is-it-legal-to-recurse-into-main-in-c/4519407#4519407).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return:

```
void somefunc() {
    if (something)
        if (something_else)
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can return from a void function. You just cant return an object.

As a further note, you should never be calling `main`. You could make this compile by putting `continueChoice` under main and forward declaring it, but you would then be creating an infinite recursive loop which is very bad for everything.

Comment: I managed to fix this problem by using a series of if, while, and else functions. Now it works perfectly. Thank you all for your help!